# How to generate delay in verilog for synthesis?

Tags: verilog

I Want to Design a Verilog code for Interfacing  16*2 LCD. As in LCD's to give "command" or "data" we have to give LCD's Enable pin a "High to low Pulse " pulse that means

```
**E=1;
Delay();//Must be 450ns wide delay
E=0;**
```

This the place where I confuse I means in Verilog for synthesis  **#** are not allowed so how can I give delay here I attached my code below. **It must be noted that I try give delay in my code but I think delay not work so please help me to get rid of this delay problem......**

```
             ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
             ////////////////////LCD Interfacing with Xilinx FPGA///////////////////////////////
             ////////////////////Important code for 16*2/1 LCDs///////////////////////////////// 
             //////////////////Coder-Shrikant Vaishnav(M.Tech VLSI)/////////////////////////////
             ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

 module lcd_fpgashri(output reg [7:0]data,output reg enb,output reg rs,output reg rw ,input CLK);
        reg [15:0]hold;
        reg [13:0]count=0;
        //Code Starts from here like C's Main......
        always@(posedge CLK)
        begin
        count=count+1; //For Delay

       //For LCD Initialization   
        lcd_cmd(8'b00111000);
        lcd_cmd(8'b00000001);
        lcd_cmd(8'b00000110);
        lcd_cmd(8'b00001100);

       //This is a String "SHRI" that I want to display
        lcd_data(8'b01010011);//S
        lcd_data(8'b01001000);//H
        lcd_data(8'b01010010);//R
        lcd_data(8'b01001001);//I
        end


        //Task For Command

       task lcd_cmd(input reg [7:0]value); 
          begin
         data=value;
         rs=1'b0;
         rw=1'b0;
         enb=1'b1;        //sending high to low pulse
         hold=count[13]; //This is the place where I try to design delay
         enb=1'b0;
        end
        endtask


   //Task for Data      

    task lcd_data(input reg [7:0]value1);
        begin
         data=value1;
         rs=1'b1;
         rw=1'b0;
         enb=1'b1;        //sending high to low pulse  
         hold=count[13]; //This is the place where I try to design delay
         enb=1'b0;
        end 
        endtask


        endmodule
```

Comment: Watch this before you write any HDL: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rdAPXzxeaxs

Answer (score 7):

You seem to be stuck in a software programming mindset based on your code, you're going to have to change things around quite a bit if you want to actually describe a controller in HDL.

Unfortunately for you there is no way to just insert an arbitrary delay into a 'routine' like you have written there.

When you write a software program, it is perfectly reasonable to write a program like

```
doA();
doB();
doC();
```

Where each line executes one at a time in a sequential fashion. HDL does not work in this way. You need to not think in terms of tasks, and start thinking in terms of clocks and state machines.

Remember that when you have an always block, the entire block executes in parallel on every clock cycle. When you have a statement like this in an always block:

```
    lcd_cmd(8'b00111000);
    lcd_cmd(8'b00000001);
    lcd_cmd(8'b00000110);
    lcd_cmd(8'b00001100);
```

This does you no good, because all four of these execute simultaneously on positive edge of the clock, and not in a sequential fashion. What you need to do is to create a **state machine**, such that it advances and performs one action during a clock period.

If I were to try to replicate those four lcd_cmd's in a sequential manner, it might look something like this.

```
always @(posedge clk)
    case(state_f)
       `RESET: begin
           state_f <= `INIT_STEP_1;
           data = 8'b00111000;
       end
       `INIT_STEP_1: begin
           state_f <= `INIT_STEP_2;
           data = 8'b00000001;
       end
       `INIT_STEP_2: begin
           state_f <= `INIT_STEP_3;
           data = 8'b00000110;
       end
       `INIT_STEP_3: begin
           state_f <= `INIT_STEP_4;
           data =8'b00111000;
       end
       `INIT_STEP_4: begin
           state_f <= ???; //go to some new state
           data = 8'b00000110;
       end
    endcase
end
```

Now with this code you are advancing through four states in four clock cycles, so you can start to see how you might handle writing a sequence of events that advances on each clock cycle.

This answer doesn't get you all of the way, as there is no 'delay' in between these as you wanted. But you could imagine having a state machine where after setting the data you move into a DELAY state, where you could set a counter which counts down enough clock cycles you need to meet your timing requirements before moving into the next state.

Comment: +1 for `as there is no 'delay' in between these as you wanted`. But why is data assigned using a blocking assignment ?

Comment: You're right, it should probably be non-blocking, I just threw together some pseudocode and didn't proofread it sufficiently.

Comment: But sir Everything that we write inside the "Sequential Blocks" that is "Begin-End" works in Sequential Manner.....so I thing its works sequentially...If I am wrong then please tell me.....

Comment: The statements inside a block are evaluated sequentially but there is no inherent delay between those evaluations. In a testbench you can insert fixed delays in those statements, but they are not synthesizable. You must start thinking in terms of hardware, not software.

Comment: Sir But I still not know how to generate delay According to Tim Sir in Digital designing Delay is generated by using "Counter" but I not know how to make code for counter.......I mean can I place the the statement like this " N<=N+1;" in the same always block this confuses me.... so much....

Comment: There is no counter needed in Tim's code. It sends out a command once every clock cycle. The period of the clock is the delay that you get between every command.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to introduce delay is to use a counter as Tim has mentioned.
Find out how many clock cycles you need to wait to obtain the required delay (here 450ns) w.r.t your clock period.

Lets take the number of clock cycles calculated is count. In that case the following piece of code can get you the required delay. You may however need to modify the logic for your purpose.

```
always @ (posedge clk) begin
  if (N == count) begin
    N <= 0;
    E = ~E;
  end else begin
    N <= N +1;    
  end 
end
```

Be sure to initialize N and E to zero.

Comment: Sir I am confuse to use "counter" for generating  "delay" in your code I know counter are used for generating delay but not know how to use it according to requirement ......I mean why you use if and else condition like a flip-flop and why you use "E".....I mean why you not use simply always and inside it place "N<=N+1;"........

Comment: When you use just always there is a delay involved but how would you get it in to your logic ? Here "E" can be considered as an enable/clock_enable for your logic. So every time the count is reached i.e, you required delay is attained the enable/clock_enable toggles. I used "E" since in your requirement you had mentioned it as the same.  see below.                                                       E=0
<Delay>
E=1

Comment: Sir can I use like this ....Let us consider 1 count=1ns then for 450ns I need 450 counts then according to you can this works always@(posedge clk)begin "mylogic" count<=count+1; if(count==450)begin disable end end.......

Answer (score 0):

Check the clock frequency of your FPGA board and initialize a counter accordingly. For example, if you want a delay of 1 second on an FPGA board with 50MHz clock frequency, you will have to write a code for a counter that counts from 0 to 49999999. Use the terminalCLK as clk for your design. Delayed clock input will put a delay to your design. The psuedo code for that will be:

```
module counter(count,terminalCLK,clk)
parameter n = 26, N = 50000000;
input clk;
output reg [n-1:0] count;
output reg terminalCLK;
always@(posedge clk)
begin
  count <= count + 1;
  if (count <= N/2)
      terminalCLK <= ~terminalCLk;
  if (count == N)
      terminalCLK <= ~terminalCLk;
end
```